# How to parse a CSV file if the column I want to Parse is in the middle of the CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV Data as below,

```
Schedule Start Time Schedule End Time   Interval    System IP - Login User
3-30-2018 1:22  03-30-2018 02:21    00 hour 5 minute    10.1.1.3


Grep Command Result         

Schedule Time   ECM MAC ImageName   
03-30-2018 01:22    B4:A5:EF:F2:27  UNAVAILABLE 
03-30-2018 01:27    B4:A5:EF:F2:27  UNAVAILABLE 
03-30-2018 01:32    B4:A5:EF:F2:27  UNAVAILABLE 
03-30-2018 01:37    B4:A5:EF:F2:27  UNAVAILABLE 
03-30-2018 01:42    B4:A5:EF:F2:27  UNAVAILABLE 
03-30-2018 01:47    B4:A5:EF:F2:27  UNAVAILABLE 
03-30-2018 01:52    B4:A5:EF:F2:27  UNAVAILABLE 
03-30-2018 01:57    B4:A5:EF:F2:27  UNAVAILABLE 
03-30-2018 02:02    B4:A5:EF:F2:27  UNAVAILABLE 
03-30-2018 02:07    B4:A5:EF:F2:27  UNAVAILABLE 
03-30-2018 02:12    B4:A5:EF:F2:27  UNAVAILABLE 
03-30-2018 02:17    B4:A5:EF:F2:27  UNAVAILABLE
```

I want to parse `Schedule Time,ECM MAC,ImageName` these columns ,
How can I do it in python, I Tried

```
file1='testcsv.csv'
red=pd.read_csv(file1,skipinitialspace=True,usecols=['Schedule Time','ECM MAC','ImageName'])
print red
```

But I'm getting,

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1740, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Usecols do not match names")
```

Can Anyone suggest the best solution?Thanks

Comment: No repro. Pandas loads the file correctly on my machine.

Comment: I'm Sorry, I'm should search columns "Schedule Time,ECM MAC,ImageName" and not "Schedule_Start_Time','Schedule_End_Time','Interval"

Comment: That csv doesn't _have_ those columns, though. Are the first 6 lines garbage? Or could there fewer or more lines of garbage? It's unclear how your data is formatted.

Comment: I want to read first 6 lines and also "Schedule Time,ECM MAC,ImageName" in line 7 and its corresponding values as new data frames

Comment: I have edited it , should be clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can parse that easily with  read_csv. But you can just skip the first rows and get to the point the information is located:

```
pd.read_csv('schedule.csv',skiprows=8, sep=' ', 
            index_col=False, skipinitialspace=True,  
            names=['Schedule Time', 'ECM', 'MAC', 'ImageName'])`
```

This is using "names" for the colum names. It is setting the separator to be ' ', as the default is ','  and is skiping the first rows of information.  The index_col=False force read_csv to not using the first column as the index column.